# Quiero aplicar estilo al contenedor de un elemento por medio de un this o parent

Tags: jquery, css

Quiero que me seleccione los elementos que se le de click para darle estilo

```
 <div id="cont-categoria" class="centFRH">
        <div id="categoria">
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 1' iden='1'>Muros al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 2' iden='2'>Rey al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 3' iden='3'>Reina al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 4' iden='4'>Defensas al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 5' iden='5'>Tropas al Maximo</div></div>      
     <div class="mensCateg" class="centB">Selecione las Categorias</div>
 </div>
```

** Funciones Jquery **

```
    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               var e = $(this).clone();
               var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

               if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
                    $("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).remove();
                    $(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg");*no funciona*
               }else{
                 $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');           
                 $(".cont-optionElement").addClass("estilSelectCateg");*no funciona*
               } 
           });

            $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               $(this).remove();
            });


        });
  </script>
```

Comment: Quien me ayuda porfa

Comment: $(this).parents(''.cont-optionElement").find("."+identificador); --- Encontre esto, sera que me sirve

Comment: No creo que no te sea posible **explayarte** con coherencia. Comunícate a la altura y explica (editando) con solvencia lo que tratas de hacer y lo que hace actualmente el código que has publicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siendo sincero me costo entender tu pregunta, te recomendaría ser mas especifico al formular una pregunta si quieres una respuesta pronta.

Usando parent checa la linea:

```
$(this.parentNode).removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
```

Creo que quieres algo asi:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               var e = $(this).clone();
               var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

               if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){
                    $("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).remove();
                    $(this.parentNode).removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
               }else{
                 $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');           
                 $(this.parentNode).addClass("estilSelectCateg"); 
               } 
           });

            $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
             let clases = this.classList;
             
             let miCosa = $(`#categoria .${clases[0]}.${clases[1]}`)[0].parentNode;
              
              $(miCosa).removeClass("estilSelectCateg");
               $(this).remove();
            });


        });
```

```css
.estilSelectCateg { background-color: red; }
.cont-optionElement { border:1px solid blue; padding:10px }
.elemento{ border:1px solid green }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="cont-categoria" class="centFRH">
        <div id="categoria">
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 1' iden='1'>Muros al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 2' iden='2'>Rey al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 3' iden='3'>Reina al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 4' iden='4'>Defensas al Maximo</div></div>
          <div class="cont-optionElement">
             <div class='elemento 5' iden='5'>Tropas al Maximo</div></div>      
     
     <div class="mensCateg" class="centB">Selecione las Categorias</div>

     <div id="campoBusq" style="border:1px solid black; min-height:50px; margin-top:16px">
      
     </div>
 </div> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes razon cuesta un poco entender la pregunta, como la respondes es la misma manera en la que entendi, espero sea lo que Necesita.

Comment: No amigo, solo busco seleccionar con this a los div: ( elemento )  para darle el estilo a cont-optionElement pero solo al div: que se vaya seleccionando

Comment: Busco algo así: $(".cont-optionElement").addClass("estilSelectCateg"); pero tomando en cuenta; que el this va a seleccionar los divs: ( elemento ) para aplicarle la clase a sus contenedores llamados cont-optionElement

Comment: :s Te deje un fragmento de código por que no lo ejecus y lo tomamos como base para saber que quieres hacer @gam

Comment: Amigo solo falta darle estilo, el resto del código esta bien, solo falta 1 linea de codigo: estoy investigando y encontré el uso de parent; tendría que probarlo asi $(this).parents('.cont-optionElement').addClass("esrilSelectCareg") es decir; quiero que seleccione a cualquier elemento que tiene como clase; (elemento 3)por ejemplo y que parents busque su padre contenedor para luego asignarle con addClass el estilo a .cont-optionElemt

Comment: Edite mi respuesta y agregue estilos checala $(this.parentNode).removeClass("estilSelectCateg"); @Gamez

Comment: Ok en cuanto la pruebe te aviso

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu ayuda, apesar que te costo entender; aveces me cuesta especificar con palabras concretas sobre el problema pero la verdad que trato que sea entendible y si ; me funciono tu codio (( $(this.parentNode).removeClass("estilSelectCateg"); y este Tambien Funciona (( $(this).parent(".cont-optionElement").removeClass("estilSelectCateg"); , el problema era que trabajara como un checkbox, cuando se marque pone la clase y cuando se desmarque quite la clase

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudarte, como reflexión al hacer $(this).parent... estas llamando a una función de jquery por tal es mas lento que hacer this.parentNode que es nativo, saludos @Gamez

Comment: amigo gracias, oye  me audas con una pregunta que publique recientemente

Comment: se llama asi ----Como quitar estilos con jquery